# Error recieved when compiling - AreaCalculationProgram.java:23: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java, double

So, here is the code. Basically it calculates the area of a circle.

import java.util.*;
  public class AreaCalculationProgram
  {
      public static void main(String [] args)

```
    {


     //Code for Circle


     int radius, areaofcircle, area;
     Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.print("Enter Diameter of Circle");
     double diameter = sc.nextDouble();
     Integer intDiameter = sc.nextInt();
     diameter = intDiameter.doubleValue();
     areaofcircle = (int) Math.pow((diameter/2),2 ) * Math.PI;
     System.out.print("AreaofCircle" + area);
```

Shown below is the error I get:

```
AreaCalculationProgram.java:23: error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
    areaofcircle = Math.pow((diameter/2),2 ) * Math.PI;
                                              ^
```

Comment: Remove the line `diameter = sc.nextInt();` which seems to serve no purpose since you input the diameter (correctly) as a `double` on the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Integer intDiameter = sc.nextInt();
diameter = intDiameter.doubleValue();
```

For edited - add cast to int:

```
areaofcircle = (int) Math.pow((diameter/2),2 ) * Math.PI;
```

Comment: So I did that and im still receiving the same error, one sec while i post it  :

Comment: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from double to int
         areaofcircle = (int) Math.pow((diameter/2),2 ) * Math.PI;
                                                        ^

Comment: Try (int) (Math.pow((diameter/2),2 ) * Math.PI);

Comment: You misspelled "Integer" in your first line of code.

Answer (score 0):

why areaofcircle is an int? Is it a problem requirement? Then you should use round/floor/ceil Math class methods (depends)